# Sitecore WFFM Form Report is not showing form data

Tags: sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers, sitecore8

I have installed WFFM on Sitecore 8.0 Update-3, and created a demo form with few fields. After submitting form I am getting success message, in log files as well didn't find any error.

But if I am checking Reports with Form Reports button (Sitecore Functionality), it is not showing any data.

I can see data in reporting database WFFM tables.

Does anyone know how we can show form data on Form Reports Page?

-Yogesh

Comment: I have a similar case: The data is submitted into database as mormally happened, I can read it with SQL Management studio, but I do not see it in reports window. Very strange, as I thought they are both sharing the same settings parameter that specifies connection string. I described that in my blog post: http://blog.martinmiles.net/post/web-forms-for-marketers-8-0-how-to-save-to-database

Comment: Thanks @MartinMilesr your blog post is really helpful to me but at this time I don't want to go for any customization.

Comment: @YogeshSharma do you have any javascript errors?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have run the **WFFM_Analytics.sql** script on your reporting database. It can be found under **/Data/WFFM_Analytics.sql**

Also check your error logs for an aggregation error. If you are getting that you need to follow this post: http://sitecorefootsteps.blogspot.co.uk/2015/06/sitecore-8-wffm-data-aggregation-error.html

Make sure that your have included the Visitor Identification in the head. For MVC this would be `@Html.Sitecore().VisitorIdentification()`.

Finally remember that the data will not be written until the session end, so it might be worth setting the session timeout to 2 minutes when testing. Then it wont take so long for the data to be stored.

**EDIT**

Are you using an IOC Container on your project? I had an issue with SimpleInjector blocking the ajax calls to the form reports data. Check your browser console for javascript errors, specifically calls to /api/sitecore/FormReports/GetFormFieldsStatistics returning error 500.

If you are getting those, check this post on a way to fix it with SimpleInjector - other IoC containers may have similar issues. http://www.sitecorenutsbolts.net/2015/07/27/Simple-Injector-and-WFFM-Controller-Injection-Woes/

-Richard

Comment: Thanks @Richard Yes I have done everything as you given, but still having same issue I can see report in SQL database but not in Form Report Page.

Comment: Are you using an IOC Container on your project? I had an issue with SimpleInjector blocking the ajax calls to the form reports data. Check your browser console for javascript errors, specifically calls to /api/sitecore/FormReports/GetFormFieldsStatistics returning error 500.

Comment: No @Richard I am not using  IOC Container

Answer (score 0):

We recently were faced with the same issue.  Data was being stored in the SQL database correctly, but the form reports were coming up blank.  As @Richard pointed out, we saw 404 errors in the console on the reports page.

I was able to solve our issue by updating our custom 404 logic to ignore paths beginning with "/api".